# Cyrillic characters trouble using @font-face

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, cyrillic

I've finished with psd and used Caviar Dreams font in my project.
This font contains cyrillic characters and they appear in photoshop, but when I use the same font with @font-face (font squirrel webfont generator) - all cyrillic characters appear as generic font characters (arial for example). Latin characters appear properly.

All the best wishes to somebody who can help me with this problem!

fontsquirrel stylesheet.css file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'caviar_dreams';
src: url('caviardreams_no_latin-webfont.eot');
src: url('caviardreams_no_latin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('caviardreams_no_latin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('caviardreams_no_latin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('caviardreams_no_latin-webfont.svg#caviar_dreamsregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

part of my style.css:

```
h2 { 
font-family: 'caviar_dreams', arial, sans-serif; 
font-size: 26px;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using the [FontSquirrel Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), you need to check the radio button “EXPERT” and then select the languages to be supported or the code range. The default is that only characters used in “Western languages” are included.

Comment: Thank you! Wish I could rep for the answer!:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm).

Special watch your meta tag, should be like this `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Answer (score 0):

See manual for including Cyrillic charset: http://php-junior.ru/web-devel/vstraivaem-shrifty-pri-pomoshhi-font-squirrel-font-face-generator